# Bitbucket server rest integration

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-server, bitbucket-api

I want to use an on prem bitbucket server using the bitbucket rest api from an application to create, update, and manage projects, repositories, teams etc while taking the parameters from my UI. And create we hooks from my java application. Can anyone point me in the right direction and a few examples to use the api for these from my spring boot project? What are the prerequisites

PS: I looked at the api docs and  tried from postman and i want to call the rest end point from my java application.

Edit: 
So I am trying to use the JAVA api given

```
<dependency>
          <groupId>com.atlassian.bitbucket.server</groupId>
          <artifactId>bitbucket-rest</artifactId>
          <version>4.0.0-eap1</version>
          <scope>provided</scope>
      </dependency>
```

I'm unable can someone point me to the right direction to initialize or configure the BitBucketClient in my Java code. I don't know how to start calling my local bitbucket server

Comment: Hi there, welcome to SO! This question is far too broad for the format of this site ([help/too-broad]). There are copious resources about REST API integration on the Web. When you run into trouble, please return for help!

Comment: I want to use the dependency provided 



 <dependency>
    <groupId>com.atlassian.bitbucket.server</groupId>
    <artifactId>bitbucket-rest</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0-eap1</version>
</dependency>
Can someone point me in the right direction to use this and create a new repository or users from Java code using maven? 



Cheers!